# Populating a dropdown menu in Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I would like to populate a drop down list using values from the database. I would like to know how I can add to the dropdown list both the display member and value member straight all from the database

Display Name: Account_Name
Member Value: Account_ID

Is this possible? If yes, How is it done

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are binding programatically using a datatable/datareader or similar. Use the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` Properties. e.g.

```
DropDownList.DataValueField = "Account_ID"
DropDownList.DataTextField = "Account_Name"
```

**EDIT**

For a combo box with a datareader you would use something akin to the following

```
YourComboBox.DataSource = yourDataReader
YourComboBox.ValueMember = "Account_ID"
YourComboBox.DisplayMember = "Account_Name"
```

Comment: I've added a rough template for using a combo box to the answer.